# Android Kotlin Write File to 'Files' -> 'Documents' - How do I get a URI?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-external-storage

I'm trying to write a file from my Android App with Kotlin.  I see the reference material on the android developer site. [Android Developer - Access Documents...](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#use-cases).  I would like to use what Android is recommending.

When I try and use the context to get the external directory URI, I only get an optional File rather than an URI.  As would be expected, I get an error because I'm trying to pass a File? to a URI parameter.

Question is, how do I get the URI to the 'Files' app 'Documents' directory?  Alternatively, should I be using a different function call to write the file to 'File' -> 'Documents'

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

minSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Function from android site.

```
val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/csv"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myToyBox.csv")

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
        // putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}
```

My function call attempt

```
private fun downloadFile() {
    val uri = context?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) // <- returns a File? 
    createFile(uri)  // <-- needs a URI
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the integration to the 'Files' app to work, but I did get access to the "Share" to work allowing me to email the file.

Most of what is the Android page and its links as well as many stackoverflow pages [Android Secure Fiile Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing)

**High Level**

1. Add the provider to your manifest
2. Add a res -> xml -> file_path document with the file share 'paths' location
3. Write the code to share the file using the 'paths' location

**Detailed Steps**

1. Update the manifest -> application section with the 'provider' details

   <manifest
   ...
   <application
   ...

   ```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAPP.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
   ```
2. Add a res -> xml -> file_path document with the file share 'paths' location

If you don't already have an xml directory/package under the res location (i.e., where your layouts are, add it and add a file.  I called mine file_paths.  You may already have one depending on what you already coded.  I wrote my document to share to the docs/ folder.  This locaiton will be needed in the actual code.

docs/ is located `File(requireContext().filesDir, "docs")`
docs/ is located in the emulator under `data/data/com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAPP/files/docs`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
</paths>
```

3. Write the code to share the file using the 'paths' location and the fileprovider reference

   private fun downloadFile() {

   ```
    val filePath: File = File(requireContext().filesDir, "docs")
    filePath.mkdirs()
    val newFile = File(filePath, "MyToyBox.csv")
    newFile.delete()
    newFile.createNewFile()
    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireContext(),
        "com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAP.fileprovider",
        newFile
    )

    val CSV_HEADER = "Series,My Toy Box ID,Debut Year,Phase,Wave,Action Figure Package Name," +
            "Movie Scene," +
            "Estimated New Value,Have the New Figure,Have New Count," +
            "Want the New Figure,Want New Count," +
            "Sell the New Figure,Sell New Count," +
            "Order the New Figure,Order New Count," +
            "Order from Text," +
            "Have the Loose Figure,Have Loose Count" +
            ",Want the Loose Figure,Want Loose Count" +
            ",Sell the Loose Figure,Sell Loose Count" +
            ",Notes" + "\n"

    var fileWriter: FileWriter? = null

    try {
        fileWriter = FileWriter(newFile)

        fileWriter.append(CSV_HEADER)

        figureList.forEach { figure ->

            val specifics = figure.specifics

            val noText = "No"
            val yesText = "Yes"

            val new_haveCount = specifics.new_haveCount.toString()
            val new_wantCount = specifics.new_wantCount.toString()
            val new_sellCount = specifics.new_sellCount.toString()
            val new_orderCount = specifics.new_orderCount.toString()
            val new_orderText = specifics.new_orderText

            val loose_haveCount = specifics.loose_haveCount.toString()
            val loose_wantCount = specifics.loose_wantCount.toString()
            val loose_sellCount = specifics.loose_sellCount.toString()

            // set yes/no text based on count
            val new_haveTheFigure = if (specifics.new_haveCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val new_wantTheFigure = if (specifics.new_wantCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val new_sellTheFigure = if (specifics.new_sellCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val new_orderTheFigure = if (specifics.new_orderCount == 0) noText else yesText

            val loose_haveTheFigure = if (specifics.loose_haveCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val loose_wantTheFigure = if (specifics.loose_wantCount == 0) noText else yesText
            val loose_sellTheFigure = if (specifics.loose_sellCount == 0) noText else yesText

            val notes = specifics.notes

            // formatted value
            var newValueString = kUnknownMTBValue
            val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
            currencyFormat.maximumFractionDigits = 2
            currencyFormat.currency = Currency.getInstance("USD")
            if (figure.saleSummary != null) {
                val formattedValue =
                    currencyFormat.format(figure.saleSummary!!.estimatedValueMean).toString()
                newValueString =
                    context?.getString(R.string.saleSummaryValueCount,
                        formattedValue,
                        figure.saleSummary!!.saleCount).toString()
            }

            // need to escape , with \" in front and back, such as in wave and names.
            val row: String = "\"${figure.series.seriesName}\"," +
                    "${figure.figureUniqueId}," +
                    "${figure.debutYear}," +
                    "\"${figure.phase}\"," +
                    "\"${figure.wave}\"," +
                    "\"${figure.figurePackageName}\"," +
                    "\"${figure.scene}\"," +
                    "\"$newValueString\"," +
                    "$new_haveTheFigure,$new_haveCount," +
                    "$new_wantTheFigure,$new_wantCount," +
                    "$new_sellTheFigure,$new_sellCount," +
                    "$new_orderTheFigure,$new_orderCount," +
                    "\"$new_orderText\"" +
                    ",$loose_haveTheFigure,$loose_haveCount," +
                    "$loose_wantTheFigure,$loose_wantCount," +
                    "$loose_sellTheFigure,$loose_sellCount," +
                    "\"$notes\"" + "\n"

            fileWriter.append(row)
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Writing CSV error!")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    fileWriter!!.close()

    createFile(contentUri)
   ```

   }

   private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {

   ```
    val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pickerInitialUri)
        type = "text/plain"
        setDataAndType(pickerInitialUri, requireContext().contentResolver.getType(pickerInitialUri))
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "My Toy Box"))
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not well versed with Kotlin,

```
String extDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath();
            File folder = new File(extDir, FOLDER_NAME);
    
         
            try {
                final File file = new File(folder, FILE_NAME);
                file.createNewFile();
```

or you could use (if you want Uri),

```
File myFile = new File(extDir, FOLDER_NAME);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile() //last parameter in this method shall be myFile
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me get to the solution, the Kotlin version is `val myToyBoxFile = File.createTempFile("MyToyBox", "csv")` and `val uriForFile = Uri.fromFile(myToyBoxFile)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just build up an uri yourself. You have to let the user choose a directory or file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT, ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_,PICK.

Once you have done that you can use that uri for INITIAL_URI the next time.

Comment: Thank you - I misunderstaood how the intents worked.  I thought the intent created the file for me.  I see from your example that I need to create the file and then "pass" the file to the intent to save the file to Files->Documents.

Comment: No. Not at all. With such intents you can let the user choose a file or directory.